# JQuery UI - resizable('destroy') not working with setTimeout fn

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-resizable

Here is the jsFiddle [demo link.](http://jsfiddle.net/e2yfC/43/)

I can see the alert getting fired after 5 secs, but the destroy is not working..

Pls make any suggestions or alternatives.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the **DEMO** [Here on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2yfC/44/)

actually `this` is not accessible `settimeout`

Comment: howcome this object does not have scope inside the Settimeout fn ?

Comment: because it written independently, outside this scope of above this